# Why Ubuntu 14.04 suddenly freezes sometimes?

Tags: 14.04, freeze

Sometimes while surfing/reading a PDF/whatever Ubuntu completely freezes. I cannot control neither touchpad nor keyboard, so I use the combination Alt + Stamp + R + E + I + S + U + B to restart it.

Any suggestion on how to fix this?
Thankss

EDIT 2:

My laptop is an Asus K53S.

Driver info:

```
ale@ale-K53SC:~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF119M [GeForce GT 520MX]
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001051sv00001043sd00001762bc03sc00i00
driver   : nvidia-304-updates - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-331 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
driver   : nvidia-304 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-331-updates - distro non-free
```

Other info:
    ale@ale-K53SC:~$ lspci -b

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [GeForce GT 520MX] (rev a1)

03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 100

04:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller

05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)'
```

Comment: Please also include information about which proprietary drivers you've installed. Easy way is running `ubuntu-drivers devices` in the console/terminal.

Comment: @gertvdijk I edited the question with that info as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had also this issue with my Dell E6520 with Nvidia NVS 4200M (Graphics issue).

Search for "Additional Drivers" in unity and there changed from "nouveau" driver to "proprietary, tested".

Comment: Already done that, I saw that there are two kind of this driver: binary and legacy binary. Does it change something?

Comment: I used the binary version on my system.

Comment: Me too, I really don't understand..

Comment: The difference between the two drivers is that the legacy drivers are intended for the video cards which are no longer supported by Nvidia in the official driver. So if you use hardware not older then 8 years you can use the binary one.

Comment: k cool, my laptop is 3-4 yo so it shouldn't be a problem, however these random freezes keep occurring. Besides that Ubuntu works flawlessy, but it's pretty annoying for this reason..

Comment: Found something where the touchpad causes the freeze. Somebody else with your type of laptop also has the bug. Try working with external mouse whole the time and check if you then have a freeze.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me too. I just press ctrl + alt + f1 and then ctrl + alt + f7 and it works again. It's really weird.